# Load files using a table of contents in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following code to load SQL scripts from a folder and execute them.

```
foreach ($sqlScript in Get-ChildItem -path "$pathToScripts" -Filter *.sql | sort-object) {  
            Write-Host "Running Script " $sqlScript.Name

            #Execute the query
            switch ($removeComments) {
                $true {
                    (Get-Content $sqlScript.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -replace '(?s)/\*.*?\*/', " " -split '\r?\ngo\r?\n' -notmatch '^\s*$' |
                        ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
                }
                $false {
                    (Get-Content $sqlScript.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -split '\r?\ngo\r?\n' |
                        ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've been asked if its possible to have some sort of table of contents to execute these files in a particular sequence without having to rename them. Is it possible to have a comma delimited file that I could loop through and load each file in the same sequence?

Edit

This is the code I think I'm going to go with:

```
 Get-Content $executionOrder
            ForEach ($file in $executionOrder) {
                $sqlScript = $pathToScripts + "\" + $file
                Write-Host "Running Script " $sqlScript.Name

                #Execute the query
                switch ($removeComments) {
                    $true {
                        (Get-Content $sqlScript -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -replace '(?s)/\*.*?\*/', " " -split '\r?\ngo\r?\n' -notmatch '^\s*$' |
                            ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
                    }
                    $false {
                        (Get-Content $sqlScript -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -split '\r?\ngo\r?\n' |
                            ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `foreach ($sqlScript in Get-ChildItem -path "$pathToScripts" -Filter *.sql | sort-object)` - > `foreach ($sqlScript in (Import-CSV $pathtoCSV))` would be all you need to change and then have a CSV with a name,fullname columns and nothing else would have to change.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines but will will have only the file name and append it to the path supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a comma delimited file that I could loop through and load each file in the same sequence

Yes. You just need to update your outer look logic to account for that input. With only minor changes you can get what you want.

```
foreach ($sqlScript in (Import-CSV $pathtoCSV)){
    # Process file.
}
```

That would work if you wanted a CSV file input as you requested. In comments it looks like you are getting a static list of file names in a predefined directory.

```
$pathToFileList = "C:\Bagel.txt"
$rootScriptDirectory = "\\path\to\scripts"
$removeComments = $true

Get-Content $pathToFileList | ForEach-Object{
    # Build the full file paths
    $scriptFilePath = [io.path]::Combine($rootScriptDirectory,$_)

    # If this file actually exists then it should be processed
    If(Test-Path $scriptFilePath -PathType Leaf){
        # Get the file contents
        $fileContents = Get-Content $scriptFilePath -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String

        # Clean the file contents as required
        if($removeComments){
            $queries = $fileContents -replace '(?s)/\*.*?\*/', " " -split '\r?\ngo\r?\n' -notmatch '^\s*$'
        } else {
            $queries = $fileContents -split '\r?\ngo\r?\n'
        }

        # Execute each query of the file 
        $queries | ForEach-Object{
            $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim()
            $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }

        # Hilarity ensues

    } else {
        Write-Warning "Could not locate the file '$scriptFilePath'"
    }
}
```

The features of `switch` are a little wasted here since you only have two states. Move the things that actually get changes into an `if` block. Get the file list and test that the file exists. Open it and parse the queries from it with your already set logic.